# What's the difference between the various kernel-debug*.rpm files created after rpmbuild?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I build Fedora Linux kernel (`` rpmbuild -bb --target=`uname -m` kernel.spec ``) [according to this guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel), and now I have among others:

- kernel-debug-debuginfo-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~360MB)
- kernel-debuginfo-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~360MB)
- kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~51MB)
- kernel-debug-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~67MB)
- kernel-debug-devel-3.18.6-100.pae_sw_tal.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~10MB)
- some others...

What's the difference between them and which one should I install if I want a development (debug-able build) version?

Comment: Can you show your .spec file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can find following information on rpmfind.net
just put `kernel-debug-debuginfo` in the search and it will tell you what it is.

Similarly for other packages.

for e.g.

```
kernel-debug-debuginfo-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

This package provides debug information for package kernel-debug. This is required to use SystemTap with kernel-debug-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm

And I think you need `kernel-debug-3.18.6-100.myself.fc20.x86_64.rpm (~67MB)`

look at the options of `rpmbuild` for creating less files. Options like `--without devel --without debuginfo`